# What is wrong with this super simple formula?

Tags: math-mode

Maybe I am tired and cannot figure out this simple problem. Here is my short `MWE`

```
\documentclass [11 pt, xcolor=pdftex,x11names,table]{beamer} 

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
        \begin{block}{Approximation for expected waiting time}
            \[
            T_q \approx a \times \frac{u^\sqrt{2(c+1)}}{1-u} \times \frac{CV^2_a+CV^2_p}{2} \]
\end{block}
\end{frame}


            \end{document}
```

when I try to compile it, I get `Missing{inserted \end{frame}`

Am I making a mistake?

Comment: The superscript needs to be in `{...}`, so you'll have to use `u^{\sqrt{2(c+1)}}`.

Comment: Jake is right. I don't think there's a `11 pt` option in `beamer`; on the other hand in all classes that support it, it should be `11pt` without a space.

Comment: Since Jake's comment should work fine, and it's just a small mistake, there's no need to keep the question open, so we will close it.